# Get an error: localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: laravel

I have a custom middleware `CheckIfUserHasStore` that checks if user has created a store.

```php
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $store = Store::whereUserId(\auth()->user()->id)->first();
        if (!$store) {
            return redirect()->route('owner.stores.create');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

and in my `web.php` with a middleware `has_store`

```php
 ...
Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:store_owner', 'has_store'])->group(function () {
 ...
});
```

I keep getting this error on browser `localhost redirected you too many times.`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This is morre likely your desired route is not reached. You have your auth routes inside the Route group, and you are redirecting the user from the middleware to a route which is inside the route group and hitting the same middleware causing a redirect loop

Comment: thanks I just have to separate the route